# Xamarin toolbar item changes color after its clicked if Navigation occurs in IOs

Tags: ios, xamarin, toolbar

I have a toolbar item implemented in Xamarin Forms project in xaml like this.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="Create"  Command="{Binding AddNewCabin}"  Text="Add Cabin"  ></ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

The command AddNewCabin is binded to a navigation method.

When I come back from the next page the text for the tool bar item is paled out like a visited link. I have no idea how to turn off that kind of behavoiur.

I thought that was an issue with a click event however I tried binding the click or the command to an empty method and the text is not paled out. It is only paled out if there is some Push navigation that occurs afterwards using this event.

I have also tried navigating using other events on the same page from listview for example and in that case the toolbar item is also NOT paled out.

So the only occasion when it is paled out (changes color) is when I navigate using the commnd or event binding of the toolbar item. In all other cases this doesn't occur and I have no idea why. Does anybody know? Thanks.

PS. I Aam testing in IOs.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I cannot reproduce behavior of your toolbar item. On my machine navigating from toolbar item works perfectly. Check my gif. Colors of button "Add" are switching properly.

[image: gif of my reproduction]

You should try removing and adding your button on the OnAppearing event.

But this is very strange behavior. Can you post more code of your implementation?